# error with destroying session in codeigniter

Tags: php

I got problem with destroying session in php using code igniter.I have used the given code:
Controller: home.php

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Please login to continue');
    redirect(base_url().'home/index','refresh');
}
```

and in View: profile.php

```
<a href="<?php  echo base_url();?>home/logout">Logout</a>
```

Once I clicked in "Logout" , the page is redirected in "home/index" page, as mentioned in logout function in controller home.php.But when I clicked in backward button in browser,the page is directed to profile page(the page which loads when the user login.)Please suggest me the answer,how to destroy that session and why my flashdata is also not working.

Comment: I think you need a leading slash since `base_url` doesn't contain a trailing slash - `<a href="<?php  echo base_url();?>/home/logout">Logout</a>`

Comment: Trailing slash is not the problem,as The function logout() is called and the page is redirected to 'home/index'.

Comment: You're trying to set flashdata after destroying your session.  Read "Destroying a Session" on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html - _This function should be the last one called, and even flash variables will no longer be available_

Answer (score 0):

**You can try something like this**

```
function logout(){

         $this->CI =& get_instance();   
         $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
         $msg= $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Please login to continue');
         $data = array();

         //...

         $data['msg'] = $error;
         $this->load->view('someview',$data);
         redirect(base_url().'home/index','refresh');
}



// And in your view file

<?php if($msg) : ?>
<div id="msg_text"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```